# C# USB driver from C++

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke

I've a problem trying to call *SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces* from C#. It always returns 1784 error code ("The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation").
On the same machine if I execute the corrisponding C++ code the function is successful.
This is my C# code:

```
        Guid classGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DFU; // Guid(0x3fe809ab, 0xfb91, 0x4cb5, 0xa6, 0x43, 0x69, 0x67, 0x0d, 0x52,0x36,0x6e)

        IntPtr hDevInfo = Win32.SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref classGuid, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, Win32.DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | Win32.DIGCF_PRESENT);
        if (hDevInfo.ToInt32() == Win32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("read hardware information error");
        }
        else
        {
            uint i = 0;
            SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA();
            devInfoData.classGuid = Guid.Empty;
            devInfoData.devInst = 0;
            devInfoData.reserved = IntPtr.Zero;

            bool result = Win32.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, devInfoData);
            if (false == result)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (error != Win32.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }

            SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA ifData = new SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA();
            ifData.cbSize = 50;
            ifData.Flags = 0;
            ifData.InterfaceClassGuid = Guid.Empty;
            ifData.Reserved = IntPtr.Zero;

            bool result2 = Win32.SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, IntPtr.Zero, ref classGuid, i, ref ifData);
            if(result2 == false)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                if (error != Win32.ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                    throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }
        }


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SP_DEVINFO_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA));
    public Guid classGuid;
    public uint devInst;
    public IntPtr reserved;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public class SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA
{
    public uint cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));
    public Guid InterfaceClassGuid;
    public uint Flags;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
}

public class Win32
{
    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetupDiGetClassDevs(ref Guid ClassGuid, IntPtr Enumerator, IntPtr hwndParent, uint Flags);   

    [DllImport("setupapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(IntPtr lpInfoSet, UInt32 dwIndex, SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData);

    public const int DIGCF_PRESENT = 0x02;
    public const int DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE = 0x10;
    public const long ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 259L;
}
```

And this is my C++ code:

```
    GUID Guid=GUID_DFU;  // { 0x3fe809ab, 0xfb91, 0x4cb5, { 0xa6, 0x43, 0x69, 0x67, 0x0d, 0x52,0x36,0x6e } }
    HDEVINFO info = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&Guid, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE);
    if (info!=INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  
    {
        SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA ifData;
        ifData.cbSize=sizeof(ifData);

        bool result = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(info, NULL, &Guid, devIndex, &ifData);
    }
```

The code is running on Windows 8.1 x64 and the C# application platform is x86.

Comment: Your C++ code says, `SP_INTERFACE_DEVICE_DATA` but I presume you mean `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA` to be a class in the C# code. That means that it is already a reference. You then pass the `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA` instance by reference to `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`. Which means that you are passing `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA**` rather than `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA*`, in C++ terms.

Either:

1. Change `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA` to be a struct, or
2. Leave `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA` as a class, but pass it by value. That is, as you did with `SP_DEVINFO_DATA` and `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo`.

You are setting `cbSize` incorrectly. It should be:

```
ifData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA));
```

There's no point in setting the other members of `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA` since they are ignored by the function that you call. That function's job is to populate those members.

There may be other problems. It's hard to say because you have not posted your actual code. The C++ code does not compile, and the C# code is incomplete.

Comment: Hi David and thank you very much for your answer. The problem was the SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA definition as class and not as struct.

Comment: Using a class is perfectly viable too. You did that with `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`. You just need to pass by value. Because a class is already a reference. And marshals as a pointer. Struct is good too, but then you pass by `ref`. For the sake of your sanity you should probably try to use the same technique for all these C++ structs. That helps avoid confusion.

Comment: Now I've added a new piece of code, "SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail" and I've the same 1784 error. Do you now why?

Comment: No. I cannot see your code. The docs say *Get the required buffer size. Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail with a NULLDeviceInterfaceDetailData pointer, a DeviceInterfaceDetailDataSize of zero, and a valid RequiredSize variable. In response to such a call, this function returns the required buffer size at RequiredSize and fails with GetLastError returning ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER.* Furthermore, I think it would be unfair to have to debug the rest of your code in this question. I think I answered this question. I'm not sure what else you are expecting from this question.

Comment: This site does not work like that. You don't get to keep changing the question like that. You asked a question. Let's stick to that. Once it's done accept the best answer. If you have a new question, ask a new question.